# How Was the Speed of Light Discovered?

Tags: speed-of-light, history, speed

The title pretty much says everything; I just want to know how the [speed of light](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light#Early_history) was discovered.

Comment: This question (v2) appears to be _off-topic_ since a straightforward Google search would immediately provide the answer, cf. e.g. [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/9/2451) and [this](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/a/121/2451) meta post.

Answer (score 2):

In 1672 a Danish astronomer was the first who reportedly measured the speed of light by noticing that one of Jupiter's moons would emerge from its eclipse 11 minutes early or late depending on the time of year when the earth was closer or further away from Jupiter. His name was Olaf Romer.

Read about him [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ole_R%C3%B8mer)

Comment: I think you mean `Ole Rømer`. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ole_Rømer

Comment: Yes, there appears to be a disparity in the spelling of his name, from Olaf Roemer, and Olaf Romer to Ole Rømer. Various references spell it differently. For example: http://scienceworld.wolfram.com/biography/Roemer.html. Thanks for pointing that out.